# Autodesk forge: how capture 2d orthographic view from a 3D model can export to 2D dxf

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there a way to capture 2d orthographic view from a 3D model can export to 2D dxf using Autodesk Forge API?

The workflow I want to achieve is:

1. import a 3D file, for example STEP file.
2. capture orthographic views (standard, top, front, right, left, rear, and bottom). Ideally I want to capture all the views in a grid view.
3. Export these views into 2d vector format, for example DXF.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such functionality is built into the Forge system.

What you can do yourself is retrieve the 3D coordinates of the faces, edges and vertices of the solids defined in the Forge model and flatten them into the different 2D planes that you mention yourself.

Wireframe view is easy of course.

There may well be some open source JavaScript libraries out there that support your in doing this, for more complex hidden line and raytracing operations.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! Do you know any good libraries that can do this? I don't need to show the hidden lines.

Comment: if you can live without rendering and hidden line removal, that means a pure see-through wireframe representation. such a representation is trivial to calculate yourself with no need to use any libraries at all. i have implemented that kind of projection for the Revit API to flatten views into 2D planes, e.g., for [polygon transformation](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2008/12/polygon-transformation.html). all you need is the [projection matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)), which is applied to each vertex.

Comment: Thanks!! The link is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The workflow you describe could be achieved with no user interaction. You may want to take a look at our [Design Automation API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2), i.e AutoCAD in the Cloud. You could import the .step file in AutoCAD and use some custom package that would perform the projection and export to .dxf. That's the only Cloud product that would allow you to produce .dxf. But achieving the projection would be a fair piece of work!

Comment: Thanks Philippe! What do you mean by **custom package**? Do I need to use the actual AutoCAD desktop software to create a AutoLISP routine or record a series of actions, and then use that routine to create an **Activity** using the Design Automation API?

Comment: i think that 2D flat projection is simple, cf. my comment below  :-)